# MATILLION API Query Profile

Tags: authentication, post, etl, matillion

How to fetch data from API_2 which needs the authentication session from another POST API in API Query Profile?

Suppose I have an API_2 which can only extract data when it has access from the authentication API. In Python we create a requests session and call the authentication API using a POST method along with some body and cookies. Once the session object is initialized, we use that object to call API_2 using a GET or POST method as required.

My question is how to do this in Matillion API Query Profile. I am able to get the response from the Authentication API by setting up the endpoint in API Query Profile 1. But i am not able to fetch any data from API_2 while setting it up in another API Query Profile 2. (FYI. I have joined the output from API Query Profile 1 to API Query Profile 2, since both the profiles are in the same job) Most probably it is because the API Query Profile 2 is not connected to the authenticated session while I am creating a new endpoint in the API Query Profile 2.

How can i do this matillion?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication API should return a session token which is then used in API2 for further API calls.  You can store the session token in a job variable using the Python component, then use the session token in the API query component for further API calls.

Comment: How to access the session token?
Is some way possible through the RSD files?